Add new columns based on existing column value - pandas dataframe
I have a dataframe with one column. I would like to run some computations based on the values of these columns and add new columns with column names as a string+value of column1 in a loop.
my_list = [123, 456, 789]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['Numbers'])

    Numbers
0   123
1   456
2   789

The output of my computations based on values in the 'Numbers' column should be added as a separate column with column name as a string(say 'test)with the value in the number column as the suffix. My dataframe should have columns test_123, test_456 & test_789 added. How can this be done?
I am not able to get the column names right

I suppose the dataframe did not display properly. The 0, 1, 2 are index values and the 'Numbers' column values are 123, 456, 789

Can you show the exact dataframe with columns/values you're expecting as output?

IIUC, I think you can do something like this to create the new columns:
my_list = [123, 456, 789]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['Numbers'])
new_cols = pd.Index(my_list)
my_df['test_' + new_cols.astype(str)] = 'a'

Output:
   Numbers test_123 test_456 test_789
0      123        a        a        a
1      456        a        a        a
2      789        a        a        a


Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. I found out that my list has negative values as well. I am thinking this may create confusion if I name the columns this way, so I am going with the index value as the suffix, like test_0, test_1 etc. How do I call these columns in a 'for loop'?

Generally, in pandas you don't want to loop, you are better find a vectorize way of doing things.  If you create a new question with some mock code of what you are trying to do, I am sure we can help.

Thank you, I have submitted a new question, will post the link here when its reviewed
